# how to set segment into angular 6 route?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Issue:
I want to set some segment after user login for ex. `http://localhost:4200/#/{dynamic name}/{dynamic name}/app/..`
 My problem is I navigate `/app/...` in across application.
so I need to add all place this two segments before app.
but I want to do global so no need to change in each and everywhere. it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your router and make all other components as a child component something like this:

**ts:**

```
{
    path: ':username/:dynamicName/app',
  component: AdminComponent,
  children: [
   //provide all your other routing like
  {path: 'home', loadChildren: HomeComponent},
  // other routing components
  ]
}
```

Comment: i know this but my question is.   I write in navigation function all component. router.navigation(['app/...']). so I need to update this in all component.

Comment: is this is a cloud application?

Comment: even I had the same problem, it was a small application I changed it in all places

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in the server hosting end where the app gets deployed.

Comment: actually segment is dynamic not fixed